# Custom model binding and validation in a multi-tenant environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, .net-core

I am working on a multi-tenant .NET Core app where all the validations needs to be dynamic (Db Driven). How can I implement custom model validation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Remote Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation#custom-validation) for validations where you need to go to the server (and then the db). You need to specify the *action* and the *controller* and it will be called during validation from the client side through AJAX. Then on the server side, you can do whatever you need in order to validate. In your case you will need to check the database. Here is an example:

```
public class User
{
    [Remote(action: "VerifyEmail", controller: "Users")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

The above is using the `Remote` attribute and specifying to use `VerifyEmail` action of the `Users` controller. In `UsersController` class you will have something like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
public IActionResult VerifyEmail(string email)
{
    if (!_userRepository.VerifyEmail(email))
    {
        return Json(data: $"Email {email} is already in use.");
    }

    return Json(data: true);
}
```

The MVC framework will take care of all the AJAX(ing) for you so you do not need to worry about any of that. I have used this many times before and it works really well.